# How can I programmatically click a TreeView TreeNode so it appears highlighted in the list and fires the AfterSelect event?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a TreeView control in a Winforms app, and basically the objective is to display a form that contains a TreeView control, and I want to display the form with a node opened (easy - EnsureVisible) and selected.

The problem that I'm running into is that when I set the TreeView control's SelectedNode property, the node isn't highlighted and the AfterSelect event isn't firing as I would expect it to.  The AfterSelect thing is easy to code around, but the lack of highlighting is annoying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it because the TreeView doesn't have focus?  Does setting the TreeView's HideSelection property to False change the behavior you're seeing?

Answer (score 5):

After you set the SelectedNode.  Try selecting the treeView.  Worked for me anyway.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.treeView1.SelectedNode = this.treeView1.Nodes[1];
this.treeView1.Select();
}
```

Comment: this.treeView1.Select() had no effect for me. Setting HideSelection to false did the trick, though.

Answer (score 4):

Try this to make the selected node bold:

```
selectedNode.NodeFont = new System.Drawing.Font(
    selectedNode.TreeView.Font,
    selectedNode.TreeView.Font.Style | FontStyle.Bold);

// You need to append an emptry string to work around this bug: 
// http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937215
selectedNode.Text += string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to programmatically do this (that I have found) is to fake the click event.  I needed to do this as when I searched for a node using TreeView.Nodes.Find(), I needed it to click each level of the hierarchy on the way down.  So I basically did the following:

```
tvMyTreeView_NodeMouseClick(tvMyTreeView, new TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs(myNode, MouseButtons.Left, 1, 0, 0));
```

Which fired my event and faking a left single click on the myNode node.  Inside that event you can format e.Node however you would want to colourise it.  Hope this helps.

Comment: This is probably the closest to a real answer to the problem among all the answers I read. In my case it did the work, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay I asked the question a little bit to soon I guess.
Found a solution:

```
//clear background
RadTreeNodeCollection nodes = rtrvNetworkAll.Nodes;
foreach (RadTreeNode n in nodes)
{
        this.ClearRecursive(n);
}
//search a node with the build in find function
foreach (RadTreeNode n in nodes)
{
        this.FindRecursive(n);
}

// recursively move through the treeview nodes
private void FindRecursive(RadTreeNode treeNode)
{
        foreach (RadTreeNode tn in treeNode.Nodes)
        {
                // if the text properties match, color the item
                if (tn.Text == this.txtSearch.Text)
                {
                    tn.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                }
                FindRecursive(tn);
        }
}

private void ClearRecursive(RadTreeNode treeNode)
{
       foreach (RadTreeNode tn in treeNode.Nodes)
       {
                tn.BackColor = Color.White;
                ClearRecursive(tn);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By highlighting, I am assuming you mean to make the text bold.  It's not as elegant as some of the other client side technologies, but you could handle the node being changed and make the selected node bold with something like

```
treeNode.Font = new Font(treeNode.Font, treeNode.Font.Style | treeNode.Bold);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that the `TreeView` control did not necessarily have focus and therefore the selected node was not showing up as highlighted. The following code worked for me:

```
treeView.Focus();
treeView.SelectedNode = myTreeNode;
```

I ran into this exact issue while implementing some drag-and-drop functionality for a `TreeView` control.